# Hide rendering of partials from rails logs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, unicorn, papertrail-app

I believe the default behavior of rails logging on production is to not output the rendering of all partials. This should log in development but not on production.

However, I'm seeing this in production and I'm not sure how to remove it. My logs are too noisy. My production environment is Heroku running Unicorn and using Papertrail to view my logs. I know Unicorn does some wonky stuff with logs and to get them working properly in the first place I had to add this to my production.rb:

```
  config.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
  config.logger.level = Logger.const_get('INFO')
```

( Explained here: http://help.papertrailapp.com/kb/configuration/unicorn )

But even with log_level INFO I'm seeing huge blocks of these in all my logs:

```
Jun 25 22:15:15 tacktile app/web.1:    Rendered photos/pieces/_caption.html.erb (0.7ms) 
Jun 25 22:15:15 tacktile app/web.1:    Rendered photos/pieces/_rights.html.erb (2.1ms) 
Jun 25 22:15:15 tacktile app/web.1:    Rendered photos/pieces/_category.html.erb (4.8ms) 
Jun 25 22:15:15 tacktile app/web.1:    Rendered photos/pieces/_caption.html.erb (0.3ms) 
Jun 25 22:15:15 tacktile app/web.1:    Rendered photos/pieces/_rights.html.erb (0.4ms) 
Jun 25 22:15:15 tacktile app/web.1:    Rendered photos/pieces/_category.html.erb (4.4ms) 
Jun 25 22:15:15 tacktile app/web.1:    Rendered photos/pieces/_caption.html.erb (0.3ms) 
Jun 25 22:15:15 tacktile app/web.1:    Rendered photos/pieces/_rights.html.erb (0.3ms) 
Jun 25 22:15:15 tacktile app/web.1:    Rendered photos/pieces/_category.html.erb (1.8ms) 
Jun 25 22:15:15 tacktile app/web.1:    Rendered photos/pieces/_caption.html.erb (0.4ms) 
Jun 25 22:15:15 tacktile app/web.1:    Rendered photos/pieces/_rights.html.erb (4.6ms) 
Jun 25 22:15:15 tacktile app/web.1:    Rendered photos/pieces/_category.html.erb (2.1ms) 
Jun 25 22:15:15 tacktile app/web.1:    Rendered photos/pieces/_caption.html.erb (0.3ms) 
Jun 25 22:15:15 tacktile app/web.1:    Rendered photos/pieces/_rights.html.erb (0.4ms) 
Jun 25 22:15:15 tacktile app/web.1:    Rendered photos/pieces/_category.html.erb (4.1ms) 
Jun 25 22:15:15 tacktile app/web.1:    Rendered photos/pieces/_caption.html.erb (0.2ms) 
Jun 25 22:15:15 tacktile app/web.1:    Rendered photos/pieces/_rights.html.erb (1.8ms) 
Jun 25 22:15:15 tacktile app/web.1:    Rendered photos/pieces/_category.html.erb (6.0ms) 
Jun 25 22:15:15 tacktile app/web.1:    Rendered photos/pieces/_caption.html.erb (0.5ms) 
Jun 25 22:15:15 tacktile app/web.1:    Rendered photos/pieces/_rights.html.erb (0.8ms) 
Jun 25 22:15:15 tacktile app/web.1:    Rendered photos/pieces/_category.html.erb (1.9ms) 
Jun 25 22:15:15 tacktile app/web.1:    Rendered photos/pieces/_caption.html.erb (0.3ms) 
Jun 25 22:15:15 tacktile app/web.1:    Rendered photos/pieces/_rights.html.erb (0.7ms)
```

Comment: Have you done `heroku config:add LOG_LEVEL="info"`?

Comment: David, yes. And I've tried setting it at "debug" vs "info" to confirm that the verbosity changes. Indeed it does. But even at "info" level I still get all these rendered statements. I'm sure I can turn it down even further and hide them. But the verbosity is great *except* for these "rendered" statements for all the partials. I'd like to figure out how to hide just those.

Comment: See also this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12003652/514483

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the following answer from a papertrail:

> I think the quickest way to deal with this is to use our log filtering
>   functionality. That'll let you drop anything that matches a regex and
>   will save you from having to make any app configuration changes.
>
> In the longer term, you'll probably want to silence these messages at
>   source. Lograge is probably your best bet for that. You may find it
>   also removes a few other bits but give it a go and let me know what
>   you think.
>
> I know this is probably irrelevant to you at the moment, but for
>   future use you might also find some other useful tips here. It covers
>   lograge, removing static asset requests and unnecessary actions,
>
> Let me know if you need help with anything mentioned above.

Answer (score 25):

For Rails 4 (at least):

Try this in your config/environments/development.rb

```
config.action_view.logger = nil
```

Comment: NOTE: This is an "all or nothing" option -- it is not just for hiding partial view logs. It hides *all* view logging. (Which can be useful for debugging and trying to see specific output without being buried in view log verbosity.)

Answer (score 8):

Use [**Lograge**](https://github.com/roidrage/lograge), it removes rendering times for partials

Comment: To expand a bit on this imo incomplete/inaccurate answer: Lograge is a gem that changes the default logging format for Rails (plug 'n play). Instead of logging tons of different lines for each request it tries to fit all the relevant information into one line (request data/controller/timing etc.), using a key-value format. Partials rendering logging is disabled/skipped in the process since it is considered non-essential (at least on production systems). So yeah, I do agree that it's the best way to reformat Rails logging, but it doesn't just "remove rendering times for partials"...

Comment: Worth noting that lograge changes the order of logs, which might not be ideal for some.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of completely disabling actionview logging (as described in another answer), I opted to change the logging level for rendering to `DEBUG`.  This way, it can be easily omitted from production logs by setting the log level to `INFO` or higher.

Note, this is for rails 5.2.  I'm unsure if it would work on other versions.

```
module ViewLoggingOverride
  def info(progname = nil, &block)
    logger.debug(progname, &block) if logger
  end
end

ActionView::LogSubscriber.include(ViewLoggingOverride)
```

Relevant rails code:

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5-2-stable/actionview/lib/action_view/log_subscriber.rb

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5-2-stable/activesupport/lib/active_support/log_subscriber.rb#L93-L99

Answer (score 1):

This is so common that, in **Papertrail** emails notifying you of a logging spike, there is a link with this exact example.

[This is the link](https://blog.papertrailapp.com/more-signal-less-noise-with-simple-free-log-filtering).

I tweaked the regex a bit:

```
/\A\s{3}Rendered \w+\/_.+\.erb \(\d+\.\d+ms\)\z/
```

PS: I always found it odd they are printed at info level in the first place.

Comment: I agree; `render` should be `DEBUG` level.